# JSFL Has Been Running For a Long Time

Tags: html, jquery-animate, adobe, publish, jsfl

I have many Flash games that I am converting to canvas. The conversion to HTML5 works fine, but when I try and publish them I constantly get errors that say:

**A script in file LayerObj.jsfl has been running for a long time. Do you want to continue?**

It will not continue publishing until I press YES, but this popup comes up 20-30 times and has a minute pause inbetween. This means each file is taking a long time.

How can I turn off this popup?

[View Popup Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsBdK.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error too, when I upped the RAM on the machine (VM) it went away.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to disable warning for that session:
In a jsfl doc , execute this command 
fl.showIdleMessage(false);

More details : https://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7b87CS5.html